# How can you access Org clock times from elisp?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Here's some sample Org clock data

```
* Sample Task
CLOCK: [2014-03-31 Mon 20:01]--[2014-03-31 Mon 20:10] =>  0:09
CLOCK: [2014-03-31 Mon 19:56]--[2014-03-31 Mon 20:01] =>  0:05
CLOCK: [2014-03-31 Mon 19:50]--[2014-03-31 Mon 19:56] =>  0:06
```

I want to grab that data and do something with it.

Can I access it easily with elisp? I couldn't find any obvious looking functions.

Specifically, I'm hoping to query the document, receive a list of the clock entries as objects, and iterate over them, inspecting properties as I go. I am hoping to avoid doing any actual string parsing myself. Org parses these lines internally, so I'd like to piggyback on that if at all possible.

If this isn't possible, what's the closest I can get?

Comment: There are too many possibilities for us to reasonably interpret `grab that data and do something with it`.  Grab all 4 lines?  Grab just the 3 lines that begin with `CLOCK`?  Grab just everything to the right of `CLOCK:  `.  And then do what with it?  Here is a link to the documentation regarding rectangles:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rectangles.html

Comment: I have clarified the question now. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to verify that there is no overlap or gap between entries?  If yes, do you know that these exist?

Comment: Nope. I just want to process them.